# How to have 1 iframe align on 2 iframes

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have total 3 iframes: `iframe_top`, `iframe_left` and `iframe_right`.

I want 2 iframes `iframe_left` and `iframe_right` side by side.

And I want 1 iframe `iframe_top` above them aligned so that the left border of `iframe_top` is aligned with the left border of `iframe_left` and the right border of `iframe_top` is aligned with the right border of `iframe_right`.

I have been able to get 2 iframes `iframe_left` and `iframe_right` side by side and `iframe_top` above them:

```
<div id="div_top">
    <iframe id="iframe_top" name="iframe_top" src="">
    </iframe>
</div>

<div id="div_main">
    <iframe id="iframe_left" name="iframe_left" src="">
    </iframe>

    <iframe id="iframe_right" name="iframe_right" src="">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

But I cannot find a way to do the aligning.

I tried setting width same for the 2 divs `div_top` and `div_main` using CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
#div_top {
    width: 100%;
}

#div_main {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

But it does not affect any thing. How can I do the aligning?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use wrapper if you solely need to align them:

```css
iframe {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
iframe#iframe_top {
    width: 100%;
}
iframe#iframe_left,
iframe#iframe_right {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
iframe#iframe_left {
    float: left;
}
iframe#iframe_right {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="iframe_top" src=""></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe_left" src=""></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe_right" src=""></iframe>
```

Although the plus side of wrapper is that `<div>` comes with no border and margins and stuff by default, so they are more layout-friendly (e.g. you don't need to use `box-sizing` for `<div>`'s default style).

Comment: Thanks. When I change the height of both `iframe_left` and `iframe_right` in CSS in px, it works. But when I change the height of both `iframe_left` and `iframe_right` in CSS in %, it does not work. Why it is working in px but not in %?

Comment: @ChumboChappati Because you'll have to specify which node's height percentage you're referring to. You'll have to give their parent a `height` property, and preferable add `position:relative` to both their parent and `<iframe>`s themselves.

Comment: What I have seen is that `height` property does not work if I specify it in % but it works if I specify it in px. For example in this JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/cr5cn80y/) I have specify the height at 75% but there is no affect. Then in this JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rdnsegeo/) I have specify the height at 75px and it works. Is it a restriction that only px can be used for height in this case?

Comment: @ChumboChappati Because when you say "75% height", the browser will have to know which element's height's percentage you're talking about. If you don't give its parent a specific height (e.g. `<div style="height:auto"><div style="height:75%"></div></div>`), browser will not calculate for you.

Comment: ok I got it. Who is the parent of `iframe_left` and `iframe_right` in your solution?

Comment: @ChumboChappati `<body>` if no wrapper at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were looking for. Create a wrapper for the 2 bottom iframes. Set the first one to half the width and then position the second iframe absolute at 50% the width of the screen.

```css
#iframe_top {
    width: 100%;
}

#div_main {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%
}

#iframe_left {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%
}
#iframe_right {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%
}
```

```html
<div id="div_top">
    <iframe id="iframe_top" name="iframe_top" src="">
    </iframe>
</div>

<div id="div_main">
    <iframe id="iframe_left" name="iframe_left" src="">
    </iframe>

    <iframe id="iframe_right" name="iframe_right" src="">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I increase the height of both `iframe_left` and `iframe_right` only the height of `iframe_right` increases as you can see at JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/od7enkzw/1/ . How can I have the height same for both right and left iframes?

Comment: You can define the height through the main div and set each of the bottom iframes to 100% height which will make them fill out the full height of the main div.

http://jsfiddle.net/hanniabu/od7enkzw/2/

Comment: But why I have to define the height of `div_main` in px instead of %?  In your fiddle when I change the height of `div_main` from 200px to 200% for example, the result was not good. Is it a restriction that only px can be used for height in this case?

Comment: Yes I noticed that as well. Unfortunately I'm not sure as to why that wasn't working. However, percents are usually used mostly in widths for responsiveness while heights are for the most part defined values. If you are unsure of the exact height for whatever reason then unfortunately this won't be a good solution for you unless someone else can chime in on how the get the percentages to work.